# Snow Leopard Automator: Trying to create a workflow for converting Excel Files

Tags: applescript, osx-snow-leopard, automator, excel-2011, excel-2008

I was trying to learn the automator functions for Snow Leopard. I googled around how to use automator to create a workflow for exporting Excel documents to CSV files. I got some hits with demonstrations showing this procedure on Leopard. However, Automator is changed in Snow Leopard and I no longer see the options to handle excel files in automator.

Could someone clarify whether this feature is no longer available? Or is it that I cannot find it.

If so could you help me get started?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with a workflow like this one? It runs normally on Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6.8) with Microsoft© Excel™ 2008 (v 12.2.3).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried "automator" to convert excel file format from ".xls" to ".csv" in batch and it works very well on my osx 10.9 with Excel 2011.

Below is what I followed:

1. search automator in spotlight and run automator.
2. the first step is to choose "Service" in the window of "Choose a type for your document". 
   [image]
3. search Excel and drag "convert Format of Excel Files" to right panel of the windows. 
   [image]
4. set options "service receives selected" as "files or folders" in "Finder.app"
5. set options "format" as "CSV(comma delimited)" as shown.
6. save to "xls2csv" and you will see "xls2csv" from the dropdown menu in the menu of the Finder Window.
7. You are ready to try.